# swift calling async function without a return value

Tags: swift, async-await, concurrency

Is there anyway in swift's new structured concurrency model to do the following without a dummy bool return?

```
func do() async -> Bool {
  something()
  return true
}
async let foo = do()

//do other stuff
stuff()

//now I need to know that "do" has finished
await foo
```

I know that I can do the following but it will not run concurrently:

```
func do() async {
  something()
}
await do()
stuff()

//cannot run "stuff" and "do" concurrently
```

I feel like I am missing a basic idea here because the top block of code does what I need but feels like a hack due to the Bool return.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you're describing is a Task. For example:

```
Task { await `do`() }
stuff()
```

This will run `do()` concurrently with `stuff()`. If you need to keep track of when `do()` completes, you can await the task's value:

```
let task = Task { await `do`() }
stuff()
await task.value // Doesn't actually return anything, but will block
```

This kind of Task runs in the context of the current Actor, which is usually what you want. If you want something independent of the current Actor, you can use `Task.detached()` instead.

If you've previously used DispatchQueues, in many of the places you would have written `queue.async { ... }`, you can now write `Task { ... }`. The new system is much more powerful, but it maps fairly nicely to the old system if you want it to.

Answer (score 9):

Swift implicitly returns `Void` for non-returning function, so I guess this would be fine

```swift
func do() async {
  something()
}
async let foo: Void = do() // just explicit Void so the compiler doesn't emit a warning telling you that may not be expected

//do other stuff
stuff()

//now I need to know that "do" has finished
await foo
```